# HTML/CSS Div drops down when I zoom out

Tags: css, html

This is my website, and if you zoom out, the right DIV zooms out. Here is the CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div class="kontejner"> 
<div class="glava"> </div> 
<div class="levidiv"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Login</p></a><br/>
<a href=""><p class="meniji">Register</p></a> <div class="levigordiv"> </div> </div> 
<div class="vsebina"> </div> <div class="desnidiv"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">IRC</p></a><br/>
<a href=""><p class="meniji">Scan</p></a> <div class="desnigordiv"> </div> </div>
<div class="noga"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Home</p></a> </div> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
     padding : 0;
     margin : 0;
     border : 0;
}
body{
    background-image:url('Matrix.gif');
     opacity:6.6
}
.container{
     display : block;
     width : 1000px;
     overflow : auto;
     margin : 50px auto 0 auto;
}
.head{
background-image:url('logo2.jpg');
background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;   
     background-color : black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 100px;
     width : 994px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.leftdiv{
    background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     min-width : 70px;
     min-height : 80px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.leftupperdiv{
    opacity:0.8;
     background-color: black;
     float : none;
     clear : both;
     height : 250px;
     width : 200px;

}
.middlecontent{
     background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 600px;
     width : 592px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.rightdiv{
    background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     min-width : 70px;
     min-height : 80px;
     border: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;

}
.upperrightdiv{ ---the problematic one 
     background-color: black;
     float : none;
     clear : both;
     height : 250px;
     width : 197px;
     border-right: 1px solid green;
     opacity:0.8;
}
.foot{
     background-color: black;
     float : left;
     clear : none;
     height : 100px;
     width : 994px;
     opacity:0.8;
     border: 1px solid green;
}
```

I think the one that is causing the error is the rightdiv or upperrightdiv.

Comment: There is no such opacity value as `opacity:6.6`

Comment: Yeah I know but that's not cuasing the error....

Comment: Warn a brother before he enters the matrix!

Comment: Please demonstrate your problem in a minimal example, not by linking to an external site

Comment: Lol can anyone help?= :D

Comment: Could you show us the HTML as well.. also, have you tried a `float: left or Right` on that div?

Comment: If you zoom out of the site, about 50%, the upper right div drops down and the site breaks

Comment: <div class="kontejner">
   <div class="glava">
   </div>
   <div class="levidiv"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Login</p></a><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Register</p></a>
     <div class="levigordiv">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="vsebina">
   </div>
   <div class="desnidiv"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">IRC</p></a><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Scan</p></a>
     <div class="desnigordiv">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="noga"><br/><br/><a href=""><p class="meniji">Home</p></a>
   </div>
</div>

Comment: You can edit your post and add the code. Just click edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... If a container (including the body) is not wide enough to display both a `float` and the `static` content that follows it side by side, the static content will drop below the float instead of wrapping around it. (Looks like the situation is in reverse here for you as your floating element is dropping)

I noticed while inspecting element on your site:

```
.kontejner{
     display : block;
     width: 1000px;
     overflow : auto;
     margin : 50px auto 0 auto;
}
```

That width is probably not wide enough for all the elements, Change that to :

```
.kontejner{
     display : block;
     width: 1100px;
     overflow : auto;
     margin : 50px auto 0 auto;
}
```

and it will stay in the position you want it to.

**EDIT:** Funny... I changed the `1100px` to only `1017px` and it also remains in place.

Comment: By the way, how do I make it for all resolutions? For instance my friend has a smaller screen and has to scroll down to see the whole site?

Comment: You are so welcome :) well, you would want to move away from `static` widths and heights then and start using `percentage %` because those adjust to fit the resolution of the users screen.

Comment: How would I fix that? It's very awkward when I put percentages in, can you give me any advice?

Comment: Thanks for the wait.. Just wrote up a quick fiddle so you can use this as an example... this obviously isn't perfect but it should work on most resolutions and browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/TS63N/2/

Comment: PS.. can you tick the answer - I need some rep :) haha

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue with rounding the pixel values. After zooming out i get borders of 1.111 and other > 1px value for you borders width.

You could fix this by using `position:absolute` to position the 3 'content' divs. Or making the container a few pixels extra wide.

I can't find the reason why your borders are being widened as you zoom out.

Comment: Doesn't work, if you zoom in/out alot you can see the whole site breaks :(